# How to do inference with a tensorflow lite model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've converted a keras model and tried to do inference on a single sample following the example on the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python):

```
# Load the TFLite model in TFLite Interpreter
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter('tflite_model')
# There is only 1 signature defined in the model,
# so it will return it by default.
# If there are multiple signatures then we can pass the name.
my_signature = interpreter.get_signature_runner()

# my_signature is callable with input as arguments.
# my_signature is callable with input as arguments.
output = my_signature(x=x, shape=x.shape, dtype=tf.float32)
# 'output' is dictionary with all outputs from the inference.
# In this case we have single output 'result'.
print(output['result'])
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid number of inputs provided for running a SignatureDef, expected 1 vs provided 3
```

I am not sure what causes the error, if I try to use just

```
output = my_signature(x=x)
```

I get invalid argument x.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: check the input shape of the model and of what you are feeding in

Comment: Agree to above point on input shape. Plus You have missed allocate_tensor() after loading the lite model from interpreter. You have to pass the inputs mentioned in model as my_signature(x=np.array([3]), y=np.array([2])) . Note: on Assumption that x and y are inputs for your model , [Ref](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter#get_signature_runner)